# Material UI Tooltip appears in docked panel after opening to a new window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm currently working on a project that uses material-ui and a layout manager flexlayout-react (https://www.npmjs.com/package/flexlayout-react). The tooltip works fine when the component renders in the main window but when popped out into a new window the tooltip still appears in the main window not on the new window.

I expect the tooltip appears on the new window not on the main window when the tooltip's child is hovered.

I've written steps to reproduce and a basic code example to represent the issue under this GitHub repo: https://github.com/thewebmaster/material-ui-tooltip-on-flexlayout
As far as I understand it is because the material-ui tooltip is still using the main window/document rather than the one from the new window.

I'm just not sure how to implement it so the tooltip uses the new pop out window/document.

Flexlayout react doc mentioned something about this:

```
const currentDocument = this.selfRef.current.ownerDocument;
const currentWindow = currentDocument.defaultView!;
```

But not really sure how to implement this as I'm quite new. Any example implementations would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

I've also asked flexlayout react about the issue with another library I'm using but no response.  https://github.com/caplin/FlexLayout/issues/163

I've also put up a question on Stack Overflow about another library that I use that isn't working when on new window
[flexlayout-react - Draggable library react-beautiful-dnd not working after opening to new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67222978/flexlayout-react-draggable-library-react-beautiful-dnd-not-working-after-openi?noredirect=1#comment118913456_67222978)

But still no luck.

```
System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.19042
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.16.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE      
    Yarn: Not Found
    npm: 7.11.2 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  Browsers:
    Chrome: Not Found
    Edge: Spartan (44.19041.906.0), Chromium (90.0.818.56)
  npmPackages:
    @material-ui/core: ^4.11.3 => 4.11.4 
    @material-ui/icons: ^4.11.2 => 4.11.2 
    @material-ui/styles:  4.11.4 
    @material-ui/system:  4.11.3 
    @material-ui/types:  5.1.0 
    @material-ui/utils: ^4.11.2 => 4.11.2 
    @types/react: ^17.0.4 => 17.0.4 
    react: ^17.0.2 => 17.0.2 
    react-dom: ^17.0.2 => 17.0.2 
    typescript: ^4.2.4 => 4.2.4
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your app and / or dev tools (F12) inspection panel with the tooltip element?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky Here's a screenshot of the app when on new window you'll see the tooltip still appears from the main document window.
![Screenshot](https://github.com/thewebmaster/material-ui-tooltip-on-flexlayout/blob/main/demo/ss.png?raw=true).
More screenshots and explanation here 
[link](https://github.com/thewebmaster/material-ui-tooltip-on-flexlayout)